# Increments in \foreach loop with two variables, TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying to draw a stack of arrows at different angles in a `\foreach` loop in TikZ.  I don't want to have to declare every z coordinate and angle manually so I was using the `{1,2,...,10}` syntax but this doesn't seem to work in the example below with two variables in the for loop.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{90}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{20}{70}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_rotated_coords,scale=0.5]

\foreach \x/\y in {7/0, 8/10, ..., 10/30}
{
\draw (2, 2, \x) circle(2) node[right]{\y};
\draw[->, ultra thick, red] (2, 2, \x) --++ (\y:2) --++ (\y+180:4);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?  The code above gives the error `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

Thanks.

Comment: `tikz` seems unable to "fill in the gaps" associated with `...`.

Comment: Is the relationship between `\x` and `\y` expressable using a formula?

Comment: For this specific case, looping over `\x` only and computing `\y` with `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{10*(\x-7)}` seems to work. Can this be applied to your original problem as well?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a general relationship between \x and \y, I'd like to do it this way so that I can change \y a lot while keeping \x the same.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142188/using-computations-with-foreach-in-tikz

Comment: Is `\x` likely to change widely as well? Or is it just going to be a steadily increasing sequence of integers (such as 3,4,5,6,7,8)?

Comment: @Jubobs \x is always a series of integers, yes, like 3,4,5,6,7

Comment: @user3087409 See my latest edit, then `:)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem stems from the `...` part in the argument of the `\foreach` macro; note that it disappears if you delete `...,` from your code.

Although you can of course recognise a pattern in

```
7/0, 8/10, ..., 10/30
```

the `\foreach` macro cannot. I refer you to section 56 of the `tikz` manual and to [using computations with \foreach in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142188/using-computations-with-foreach-in-tikz) for more details about how `...` works inside the argument of `\foreach`.

In this particular case, under the assumption that `\x` represent a sequence that can be expressed by a simple enough formula—`\x` simply represents an arithmetic sequence, here—you can just use `\y` as the only loop variable and derive `\x` from the iteration variable; I've defined the latter as `\i` by using `count=\i` in the optional argument of `\foreach`, below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{90}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{20}{70}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_rotated_coords,scale=0.5]

\foreach[count=\i, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+6)] \y in {0,10,...,30}
{
    \draw (2, 2, \x) circle(2) node[right] {\y};
    \draw[->, ultra thick, red] (2, 2, \x) --++ (\y:2) --++ (\y+180:4);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try '\foreach[count=\x from 7] \y in {0,10,...,30}' and no pgfmathtrunc...

Comment: @Tarass You're right; I could do that in this specific case. However, my approach is more general, because it can be adapted to cases where the recursive formula for the `\x` sequence is different from simply `x_{n+1} = x_n + 1`.

Comment: Then on can do foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \x using \i+7, evaluate=\i as \y using 30*\i] in {0,...,3} or what other formula you want.

Comment: @Tarass But then, how would you specify `\y`? The OP [wrote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171426/increments-in-foreach-loop-with-two-variables-tikz/171430?noredirect=1#comment395369_171426) that there is no simple relation between `\x` and `\y`. I'm assuming that `\x` and `\y` cannot simply be deduced from a common variable...

Comment: If on use ... in the for each, it means that the two \x and \y have an arithmetic incrementation. Then what I have wrote works. Otherwise you have to write explicitely the parameter (even both parameters). If one is inarithmetic progression one can use your solution. But in the OP's example both are in arithmetic progression. My solution works far all type of sequences even not artiyhmetics. If \x nor \y are not a sequence, one have to givve all values explicitely.

Comment: @Jubobs: why not adding the `evaluate` option?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino You're right. I hadn't realised until now that you could use evaluate on the count variable! Thanks for the tip. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Jubobs: you're welcome :)