# "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)” Problem with foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying to make a series of circles with gradients. On the second page, which is created, there is only /2pt/1pt/2pt and on the last /20pt. I guess there's something wrong with my foreach loop, but I don't know what.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,10,0}

\begin{document}

\foreach \Radius/\j in {6.0/1, 6.05/2,...,8.0/42}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\k{\j*10}
        \useasboundingbox[fill=black] (-8.2,-8.2) rectangle (8.2cm,8.2cm);
        \fill[fill=myyellow!\k] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

<to be read again> 
                   /
l.15 }
```

Comment: Crosspost in German: https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/24430/fehler-illegal-unit-of-measure-pt-inserted

Comment: @HenriMenke The cross post seems to be deleted (after I added an answer, as you suggested me to do)....

Comment: The error is explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171430/132405): `foreach` don't recognise a pattern in a list like `{6/1, 7/2, ... , 10/5}`. The `...` is only usable with one variable. If you use a construction like `\foreach \x / \y in `, avoid using `...` in the list.

Comment: @marmot I'm sorry, I deleted the question before I saw that it was answered, because I already got the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use integers for the color fraction, and there is the option of using `count` for this very situation.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,10,0}

\begin{document}

\foreach \Radius [count=\j] in {6.0, 6.05,...,8.0}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\k{\j*10}
        \useasboundingbox[fill=black] (-8.2,-8.2) rectangle (8.2cm,8.2cm);
        \fill[fill=myyellow!\k] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really make sense to do `myyellow!420`: all values from 100 on will produce the same color.

Here the gradient goes from 2 to 84 with step 2.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,10,0}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {2,4,...,84}
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{(\x-2)/41+6}
        \useasboundingbox[fill=black] (-8.2,-8.2) rectangle (8.2cm,8.2cm);
        \fill[fill=myyellow!\x] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\end{document}
```