# ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) with \foreach with 2 variables with this simple code

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to iterate the variable i between [1,9], with the iterations with the variable j between [3,11]

```
\foreach \i/\j in {1/3,...,9/11}{}
```

So I wrote the above code, however as I run this , the error messages with

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   /
```

appears .

What can I do next?

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]

        \foreach \i/\j in {1/3,...,9/11}{
        \draw[->](\i,\i,0)--(\i,\j,0);
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is the desired result -- if you expand the first `i/j` it will result in `draw 1,3,0 to 1,3,0`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in a code.

Comment: Done of the edit.

Comment: have a  look here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171426/increments-in-foreach-loop-with-two-variables-tikz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can reduce to

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        
        \foreach \i/\j in {1,2,...,9}{
            \draw[->](\i,\i,0)--(\i,\i+2,0);
        }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]