# Foreach loop doesn't work inside mdframed to draw points

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, mdframed

In this case, I would like to plot some points from the graph of `x^2 - x - 6` using `foreach` (coordinate in the MWE). Unfortunately, when I plug the `foreach` loop, the error stated

```
Undefined control sequence. \end{axis}
```

And, I've used these reference in advance to help with my case, yet doesn't yield anywhere to the solution :

- [Increments in \foreach loop with two variables, TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171426/increments-in-foreach-loop-with-two-variables-tikz)
- [draw a plot with point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61316/draw-a-plot-with-point)

(Actually, there're more but I forgot the link, though).

Here's my code, hopefully someone be able to help it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\mdfdefinestyle{mdgreenbox}{
    skipabove = 8pt,
    skipbelow = 8pt,
    linewidth = 2pt,
    rightline = false,
    leftline = true,
    topline = false,
    bottomline = false,
    linecolor = green,
    backgroundcolor = green!5,
}

\begin{mdframed}[style=mdgreenbox]
    Lorem ipsum...
    {\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \begin{axis}[
            x = .7cm, y = .7cm,
            axis lines = middle,
            xlabel = $x$, ylabel=$y$,
            xtick = {-5, 0, 5, 10},
            ytick = {-15, -10, ..., 5},
            minor tick num = 4,
            xmin = -3.3, xmax = 4.3,
            ymin = -7.3, ymax = 5.3,
            font = \tiny
        ]
            \draw[black, thin, smooth, domain = -7 : 12] plot (\x, {(\x)^2 - 1 * (\x) - 6});
            
            % Here...
            \foreach \x/\y in {-3/4, -2/0, -1/-4, 0/-6, 1/-6, 2/-4, 3/0, 4/6}{
                \node at (\x, \y) {\textbullet};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\par}
\end{mdframed}
```

P.S. Also, is there anyway, so for each graph, I could use a definite `foreach` code to plot my points?

Comment: Well, you're nesting a Ti*k*Z picture in another one, which is definitely not recommended.

Comment: I've tried to undo the nestings, but still is not solved.

Before, I used to use that code structure to design my graph though.

Comment: Do `\node foreach \x/\y in {-3/4, -2/0, -1/-4, 0/-6, 1/-6, 2/-4, 3/0, 4/6} [circle, fill, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+2.5pt] at (\x, \y) {};` or `\fill[radius=1.25pt] foreach \x/\y in {-3/4, -2/0, -1/-4, 0/-6, 1/-6, 2/-4, 3/0, 4/6} {(\x, \y) circle[]};` The problem, yet again, was a (grouped) loop inside the `axis` environment. This makes trouble oftentimes.

Comment: Woah! It worked like charm! Thank you.

Comment: If you `declare function={f(\x)=(\x)^2 - 1 * (\x) - 6;}` as an option to the `tikzpicture` environment, you can replace `(\x, {(\x)^2 …})` by `(\x, {f(\x)})` and the points can then be placed a bit easier, too: `\fill[radius=1.25pt] foreach \x in {-3, -2, ..., 4} {(\x, {f(\x)}) circle[]};`. — By the way, is there a reason you use the `axis` environment from the PGFPlots package but not its `\addplot` command?

Comment: So, if I may conclude, the foreach loop I made should not be a nested but it should like inline or sort of like `key` from either `\fill` or `\node`, is it?

Comment: There's nothing in particular, I'm just using what I've used to. But, will do for the future. Thank you.